# resize handles on DIV using jquery resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, handle

The jQuery Resizable plugin is great, but it only changes the cursor around the edges and corners of the resizable `div`. But I need the corners of the `div` to also have the real square (or round) handles that show up in other editing programs, such as photoshop, when an object is selected for resizing. What's the quickest and stablest and simplest way to add the handles on the corners of the `div`? I need IE-compatibility (at least from IE-8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add handles in all corners of the div, use the **handles** option.

```
$('.selector').resizable({handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw'});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

Comment: Thanks! I actually had them alright. But I couldn't see them. So I realized the solution was to give a border and background to the handles in the jquery-ui CSS file.